# Gradle Error: cannot find symbol variable Settings_main

Tags: android, layout

I currently have a problem changing the layout of my Android app. It doesn't work like usual.
When I want to change the layout to the settings layout with the press of a button, it gives the error: cannot find symbol variable Settings_main.

The code where this happens is

```
final ImageButton settings = findViewById(R.id.Settings_button);
settings.setOnCLickListener(new View.onClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                setContentView(R.layout.Settings_main);
        }
});
```

[This is the error it's giving me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0sJv.png)

I have imported

```
import android.view.View;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
```

Can someone please help me solve this?
Every name and Id does match according to IntelliJ as well, so I have no idea what could possibly be going wrong.

Comment: Please cross check once, you are accessing with the same file name of the xml or not..

Answer (score 0):

File-based resource names must contain only lowercase a-z,0-9 or underscore.

Please change file name Settings_main to settings_main